# I'm getting fatal error while running laravel project php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, server, fatal-error, laravel-artisan

PHP Artisan not working, but this command works:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

I already tried:

```
composer instal " & "composer update
```

And many other commands like:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

But it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the `server.php` file is missing. Does it exists? It should be on the root directory of your application.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for sharing code/errors.